# Is this Int64 Swift Decoding superfluous?

Tags: swift, parsing, codable

I have seen a piece of code online which uses Swift Codable do decode a JSON into a struct.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let stringValue = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .someId), let value = Int64(stringValue) {
        someId = value
    } else {
        someId = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .someId)
    }
}
```

This code:

- decodes a string
- tries to parse it into `Int64`
- if it fails - it directly attempts to decode an `Int64`

My question is - is this code superfluous?

Is there any scenario where `Int64.init(_:)` from `String` would be able to decode something that `JSONDecoder.decode` wouldn't?

And actually, isn't this "decode String - init Int64" the exact same thing that `JSONDecoder` does under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not superfluous. It could be used to handle JSON that sometimes has numbers encoded as a string (within quotes), and sometimes just as a number.

For example, the JSON could sometimes be:

```
{
    "someId": "12345"
}
```

in which case you need to decode to `String`, and then `Int64.init`

And sometimes the JSON could be:

```
{
    "someId": 12345
}
```

in which case decoding to `String` would fail, and you would directly decode to `Int64`.